# RelayCommand and WeakReference

Tags: mvvm-light

I have the following:

```
public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;

    NotWorkingCommand = new RelayCommand(() => 
    dataService.GetData((item, error) =>
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
            // Report error here
            return;
        }
        WelcomeTitle = item.Title;
    }));
}
```

Can someone please explain why my `RelayCommand` would stop firing after a while? I suspect it has to do with `WeakReference` used in the `RelayCommand` but I have no experience with `WeakReference`. If I used `_dataService.GetData` instead, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

In your lambda expression, the dataService.GetData instruction won't work, because the scope of the variable dataService is only limited to the constructor.

Instead you should copy this reference to a backing field and call this instance instead.
If think you were near the solution when you say it works by using _dataService.GetData.

```
private readonly IDataService _dataService;

public RelayCommand NotWorkingCommand { get; private set; }


public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
{
        _dataService = dataService;

        NotWorkingCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
        _dataService.GetData((item, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                // Report error here
                return;
            }
            WelcomeTitle = item.Title;
        }));
    }
```

It seems that the delegate is correctly created because the reference exists when the relay command is created (in the scope of the ctor), but it can't be called at runtime because it cannot be evaluated correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I do not understand is that it was working previously until WeakReference is used in RelayCommand. In the older version of Mvvmlight, WeakReference was not used.

Comment: In the previous version, the Execute method on RelayCommand was
       `public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute();
        }` compared to now      `public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (CanExecute(parameter)
                && _execute != null
                && (_execute.IsStatic || _execute.IsAlive))
            {
                _execute.Execute();
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

marckm is not wrong here and the suggestion to use the class-level variable will work. But I would just like to clarify that the complete answer to this question should include a bit of info on "variable captures" in lambdas.

*Before* MVVMLight started to use weak references, the method-level variable dataService would by captured in the lambda expression. Normally, this variable would go out of scope once the method completes. Due to variable capture in the lambda, this would not happen here, which is why the body of the lambda would (always) work later on.

*After* MVVMLight moved to weak references, the code will initially work, but without the class-level variable (and assignment), the method-level variable will eventually be garbage collected, and the RelayCommand will then stop to work. Which is exactly what you saw here (six years ago - I know - but this question remains valid today).